# How can i filter mysql query using count()?

Tags: mysql

I am using this MySQL query to get buying frequency where buying_count is greater than 3, can anyone tell me how can I use count(id) in where clause? I tried using where count(id)>3 but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    COUNT(id) AS buying_count,
    buyer_name
FROM
    c_customer_orders
GROUP BY buyer_email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id,
    COUNT(id) AS buying_count,
    buyer_name
FROM
    c_customer_orders
GROUP BY buyer_email
HAVING buying_count > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT 
    id,
    COUNT(id) AS buying_count,
    buyer_name
FROM
    c_customer_orders
GROUP BY buyer_email
HAVING buying_count >= 3
```

Comment: how exaclty do I deserve a downvote I did not see your post at the time of my posting

Comment: You see a message that there is another answer, so you can see it.

Comment: ok tks for the info, still think it was uncalled for, way to help the community :(